# Python 3 printing datetime date as 1900?

Tags: python, datetime, format

For some reason, when I format `datetime.datetime.now()` to print the date and time nicely in Python 3, the date keeps coming out as 01/01/1900.

Here is my code:

```
print('{}'.format(str(datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%x %X'))))
```

Output: `01/01/00 13:40:11`

Any ideas on why the date is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your system time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now_time.strftime('%x %X')
'05/06/17 09:15:27'
```

you don't need .time

Comment: Thank  you all, don't know how I missed that!! haha. Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a `datetime.time` removes the date:

**Code:**

```
print(dt.datetime.now().time().strftime('%x %X'))
print(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%x %X'))
```

**Results:**

```
01/01/00 20:47:41
05/05/17 20:47:41
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call is to `datetime.datetime.now().time()`

Notice the difference between that, and `datetime.datetime.now()`

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time()
datetime.time(22, 45, 48, 610362)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 22, 45, 57, 874420)
```

You want to remove the `.time()` portion in your `.format()`.

```
>>> print('{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%x %X')))
05/05/17 22:47:30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# bytes array to Python 4 bytes float
    import struct

    fl = struct.unpack('f', b)[0]

# Python 4 bytes float to datetime.date
    date = int(fl)
    year = int(date / 10000)
    month = int((date % 10000) / 100)
    day = date % 100
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)

# datetime.date to Python float
   fl = int(date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

# float to bytes array
    byt = struct.pack('f', fl)
    return byt[:4]
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: Unpack a byte array ------> Python Int/Float (4 bytes)  --------> calculate Year, Month, Day parts ------> create  a DateTime Object.

Reversely,  a DateTime Object -----> Python Int/Float (4 bytes) -------> pack it to byte array.